# Given component holder class MainActivity does not implement interface GeneratedComponent or interface GeneratedComponentManager

Tags: android, crash, android-jetpack-compose, dagger, dagger-hilt

im creating an app with hilt DI and jetpack compose and my app crashes, when i start it. There are parts of code,where i use hilt:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesLoggingInterceptor() = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
       
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
       
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit = Retrofit
     

   @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun createsApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ImageAPIService {
       
    }


   @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): Database {
    
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesImagesPager(){}
        
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class CardScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ImagesRepository
): ViewModel() {
   
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class SearchBarViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ImagesRepository
): ViewModel() {
   
}
```

```
class ImagesRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: ImageAPIService
) {
    
    }
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class ImagesListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dbImages: Database,
    private val apiService: ImageAPIService
    ) : ViewModel() {
  
}
```

```
MainActivity: @AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {

            TestAppTheme {

                Surface {
                    SetupNavGraph(navController = rememberNavController())
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

App:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class TestApp: Application() {

}
```

AndroidManifest:
`android:name=".TestApp">`
Dependencies for hilt:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

 buildscript {
        dependencies.classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10")
        ext.hilt_version = '2.4.0'
        dependencies.classpath ("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version")
    }
dependencies:
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0-alpha03"
```

I tried to change libs version and delete parts of code, but unsuccesfully, also i watch simular questions on stack overflow ant tried solutions, that were in posts.

Comment: In your mainActivity remove **mainActivity : @AndroidEntryPoint** and jsut replace it with **@AndroidEntryPoint**